# How do I install 'z' file directory jumper on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I'm attempting to install this and running into issues. I am supposed to add a line to the ".bashrc" file? Where in the file? the bottom? the top? somewhere in the if statement? do I make it an alias?

Link to z site: https://github.com/rupa/z

Here's my .bashrc:

```
echo ". ~/z.sh" > ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Just put it anywhere. the end will do.

Comment: z.sh is in my / directory

--- .bashrc is in my /etc/ directory

--- at the end of my .bashrc, I added: `. ~/z.sh`

--- I get: `-bash: z: command not found`

Comment: Add it to your ~/.bashrc, and use an absolute path. Also, this won't affect a running shell. though you could run `. ~/z.sh` in one for that.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.bashrc --- should I just drag it from /etc/ into /? --- and what's an absolute path?

Comment: If you don't have one, create one. An absolute path is of the form `/home/user/z.sh` or similar.

Comment: ok ---- `.bashrc` now exists in my / directory --- `z.sh` now exists in my /home/ directory --- `.bashrc`'s contents can be seen ABOVE (edited my post) -- still getting --- `-bash: z: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up a second. `/etc/bash.bashrc` is the system-wide settings file for bash. `$HOME/.bashrc` (often abbreviated as `~/.bashrc`) has your user's personal settings. `~/.bashrc` is read everytime you start a new shell (open a terminal) and so is `/etc/bash.bashrc`, you don't need to copy anything from one to the other, both will be read.

So, if your system has no `~/.bashrc`, all you need to do is create one and add the relevant line to it:

```
echo ". ~/z.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

That's it.

The `.` is an alias to bash's `source`:

```
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.
```

Comment: I created ".bashrc" in my /home directory --- it's contents can be seen in my post (edited above) --- z.sh is also located in my home directory --- I still get `-bash: z: command not found`

Comment: @SamuelStiles `/home` is not your home directory, `/home/your_username` is. Both `.bashrc` and `z.sh` should be in your `/home/your_username` directory. Just run this command: `cp /home/.bashrc /home/z.sh $HOME`.

Comment: done.... stil getting `-bash: z: command not found` :S  I'm logged in as root, will that muck with things?

Comment: Correction: I had to re-open my terminal window. It now appears to be working! Thank you!

Comment: @SamuelStiles yes, `.bashrc` is read every time bash is started so you need to restart bash (open a terminal) for it to be read. If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm new to this site; is the green check mark "marking it as accepted"? I hit that.

Comment: @SamuelStiles That is the correct thing to do, yes!

Comment: @SamuelStiles welcome to SU! The general idea is that when an answer is helpful/good you [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it and if it answers your question you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101) it.